# VSCode different Theme setting for each project in a WorkSpace

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, workspace

When I build backend and frontend with the same language, JavaScript, I find it very hard to distinguish between both. Is there any way to have different themes for each project in the workspace? for example **change the file association for the frontend to show React logo** instead of the default JavaScript logo *(I use Material Icon Theme)*

```
"material-icon-theme.files.associations": {
        "*.js": "react"
        // HOW CAN I MAKE THIS APPLY FOR THE FRONTEND PROJECT ONLY?
    },
```

using the .jsx for frontend is not a good option as it will require extra work when importing things, also not all of my frontend files uses React.js. And I will lose a lot of snippets.

Comment: that is why the directory is shown in grey

Comment: I think they both are in the same color, if not maybe this is because of the blue light filter I installed, I was hoping for something clearer tho as a symbol or a completely different color. When I had Python for backend It was very easy to distinguish between both.

Comment: My workaround is using multiple VSCode instances for each project, with custom workbench color (https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=johnpapa.vscode-peacock) for distinct the VSCode instance.

Comment: @RexPan I think having multiple windows is the only way I found so far, thanks for helping

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have written the extension [When File](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.WhenFile) that allows you to change workbench colors based on the file path.

Read the extension page for the possible use cases.

An example if you have one folder open in VSC

```json
  "whenFile.change": {
    "/server/": {
      "workbenchColor": {
        "activityBar.background": "#509050"
      }
    },
    "/client/": {
      "workbenchColor": {
        "activityBar.background": "#905080"
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: @ZeyadShaban On the extension page you mention `add a file association`, do you mean, change the colors based on the languageID of the file? You can always add a feature request on the github page

Comment: Yes, for example for files in /frontend/ will have a blue javascript react icon or any icon user chooses, and for /server/ will have a normal js icon to distinguish when searching files. I know that this is hard to achieve as you will need to integrate with multiple theme extensions or create your own, so the current version is more than great.

Comment: @ZeyadShaban if you want your `.js` files in `/frontend/` to have a different icon and languageId you should use Multi Root Workspace (`File | Add Folder to Workspace`) and set `files.associations` in each individual `.vscode/settings.json`

Answer (score 1):

Give a try to Peacock theme. It gives different color to each vscode instance.
https://github.com/johnpapa/vscode-peacock

Comment: I think this works for multiple windows only but not different colors for the same window, please correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: already suggested by Rex Pan in a comment

Answer (score 0):

You could Try Using VS Code Color Themes.

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/themes

Comment: Thanks for the help, this changes the whole editor theme and can't set them separately for each project of the workspace